# copy from array to variable causes stackoverflow

Tags: c++, c, qt

I'm developing a **QT Widgets Application** with **C++**, with functions of **C**. I'm not saying I'm writing **C++**, so please avoid saying "THAT'S NOT C++". Here's my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

----------------------------------------------------------

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{

private:

    char**  NUM_ARRAY;
    char*   GUESS;
    int     DIGIT_COUNT;
    int     NUM_COUNT;

    void fill_array();
    bool num_valid(char *NUM);
};

----------------------------------------------------------

void MainWindow::fill_array()
{
    int i, j = 0;
    int START       = 1;
    int END         = 9;
    int CTR_START   = 0;
    int CTR_END     = 0;

    NUM_COUNT   = 1;
    GUESS       = (char*)malloc(DIGIT_COUNT * sizeof(char));
    DIGIT_COUNT = ui->LE_DIGIT_COUNT->text().toInt();

    char* TEMP_NUM = (char*)malloc(DIGIT_COUNT * sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; i < DIGIT_COUNT; i++)
    {
        NUM_COUNT *= END;
        CTR_START = (CTR_START * 10) + (START++);
        CTR_END   = (CTR_END * 10) + (END--);
    }

    NUM_ARRAY = (char**)malloc(NUM_COUNT * sizeof(char*));

    for (i = CTR_START; i <= CTR_END; i++)
    {
        NUM_ARRAY[j] = (char*)malloc(DIGIT_COUNT * sizeof(char));

        sprintf(TEMP_NUM, "%d", i);

        if (num_valid(TEMP_NUM))
            memcpy(NUM_ARRAY[j++], TEMP_NUM, DIGIT_COUNT * sizeof(char));
    }

    memcpy(GUESS, NUM_ARRAY[0], DIGIT_COUNT * sizeof(char)); <----- ERROR
    ui->L_GUESS->setText(GUESS);
}
```

What I'm doing is; filling a string array consisting of numbers from 1234 to 9876. These numbers doesn't include any `0`s or same digit more than once. I debug the code and everything seems fine. I cannot watch `NUM_ARRAY`; it shows `NUM_ARRAY "1234" char*`, but I am positive that the array is filled correctly, as `TEMP_NUM` and `j` shows correct values.

At the pointed line, segmentation fault occurs and I have no idea why. What am I missing here? Please note that I've tried `strcpy` with no luck and open for suggestions about using other functions for the purpose.

Comment: To start with, if you're programming in C++ why don't you use `new` instead of `malloc`? Or better yet, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of handling the memory your self?

Comment: When you are allocating memory for GUESS you are using an uninitialized variable DIGIT_COUNT . Is it correct?

Comment: Another tip, regarding your coding style: All upper-case letter names are usually used for preprocessor macros or constants.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but it's our company standard. @sajas you got it right but I have to accept the first answerer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be problematic:

```
GUESS       = (char*)malloc(DIGIT_COUNT * sizeof(char));
DIGIT_COUNT = ui->LE_DIGIT_COUNT->text().toInt();
```

ie: you use the `DIGIT_COUNT` before actually initializing it, so it has some garbage data in it.

Also:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toInt offers a way to actually check if the conversion was successful. Use it, it is there for your own good.

Comment: don't bother giving extra effort, I will be accepting your answer, I'm just waiting for the time limit to end.

Comment: @IsmetAlkan Your code also doesn't check if `malloc` returns NULL.

Answer (score -2):

I cannot see that you are freeing any resources used.

Use free() wisely...

example..

```
free(TEMP_NUM);
```

Comment: While a good comment, this doesn't actually *answer* the OPs question.